# Is it possible to use `musique` to sync with an iPod?

Tags: sync, ipod

I was reading online about a program called `musique`, so I installed it. It's quite a lot better than rhythmbox in my opinion. The only thing is I can't find a way to sync it with my iPod, make playlists, smart or normal, which is annoying because smart playlists and the ability to rate songs are key features I need to be able to manage my iPod.

If you haven't got a solution could you direct me to a different opensource program to manage my iPod that can rate songs, and create smart playlists (and sync with my iPod of course) that IS NOT Clementine, Banshee, amarok, songbird, or rhythmbox

Answer (score 0):

In my experience synchronizing iPods in Linux specially the touch ones can result into some troubles, you'll have serious trouble if you'll sync again with iTunes (wich is something every iPod user does from time to time). My suggestion is to keep synching it with iTunes (using wine or in another OS) and buy a different portable music player, an android based one could be a better choice in the future if you'd prefer using Ubuntu.